# How to add Beamer `\frametitle` to `imenu`?

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode, beamer, imenu

I know that there is `RefTeX` with its TOC, and I know how to include `\frametitle` there (see [here](http://emacsworld.blogspot.de/2008/03/getting-beamer-frame-titles-into-reftex.html)). Nevertheless, I would like to see `\frametitle` also appear in `imenu`. What would be the minimal way to get to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```el
(push '("frametitle" 2) TeX-outline-extra)
```

See the documentation for `TeX-outline-extra`. The first element of the list being added is a regexp and the second is the imenu level. You can also see `LaTeX-section-list` for the default levels that imenu uses for latex.

**Update**:

As suggested in the comments, it might be a little safer to use the following. This change makes no difference for my use though.

```el
(push '("\\\\frametitle\\b" 2) TeX-outline-extra)
```

Comment: [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Outline) also says: _A ‘^’ is automatically prepended to the regular expressions in the list, so they must match text at the beginning of the line._  Hence, I suggest you do `(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("\\\\frametitle\\b" 7))`.

Comment: That may be what it says, but that's not the regexp that is actually used. See the `LaTeX-outline-regexp` function. In any case, your regexp will prevent matching against something like `\AframetitleA{}` so I updated it. Thanks